# Pip wont install modules

Tags: python-3.x, module, pip

I was trying to install PyAudio in order to use *SpeechRecognition* but, in the mean time, I updated pip as well to its lates version, now running `pip install --user [name]` generates the following error:

```
C:\Users\carlo>pip install --user PyAduio  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 192, in _run_module_as_main  
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I updated pip because it came out with a warning:

> WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 19.3.1 is available.
>   You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Any ideas on what could be going wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble installing TextBlob with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58442401/trouble-installing-textblob-with-pip)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bpip%5d%20TypeError%3a%20%27module%27%20object%20is%20not%20callable

Answer (score 0):

There is a discussion on similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58451650/pip-no-longer-working-after-update-error-module-object-is-not-callable).

What you may try is the following.

```sh
python -m pip install PyAudio --user
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same when I installed Python 3.8 and tried to set it as project interpreter in Pycharm whrere I used Python 3.7 before. Going back to 3.7 'solved' it.

Comment: How did you rollback to 3.7?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused due to unsuccessful upgradation of pip because you were not running cmd as administrator.

However the only fix is to uninstall python from control panel and then download python and install again from their official website ;)