# pip 19.3.1 TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: pip, typeerror

pip and pip3 do give me the same error if I upgrade them to the last version which is any time I try to call them:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

Note that this error was not present on pip version 19.1.1 .

I am running Debian buster with a uname -a:
Linux *** 4.19.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.67-2+deb10u2 (2019-11-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux

And my python versions:

`Python 2.7.16
Python 3.7.3`

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble installing TextBlob with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58442401/trouble-installing-textblob-with-pip)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bpip%5d%20TypeError%3a%20%27module%27%20object%20is%20not%20callable

Answer (score 0):

Try `pip3 install --upgrade pip` with root.

`pip` version is actually 20.0.2.

After that retry your command.

Jeff