# PIP - TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, pip

Dears....

I have 2 workstations.
In workstation1 I can execute pip at windows command prompt and Anaconda Prompt:

**Windows Command Prompt**

`C:\Users\myuser>pip show datetime`

```
Name: DateTime
Version: 4.3
Summary: This package provides a DateTime data type, as known from Zope. Unless you need to communicate with Zope APIs, you're probably better off using Python's built-in datetime module.
Home-page: https://github.com/zopefoundation/DateTime
Author: Zope Foundation and Contributors
Author-email: zope-dev@zope.org
License: ZPL 2.1
Location: c:\program files (x86)\python 3.7.1\lib\site-packages
Requires: zope.interface, pytz
Required-by:
```

**Anaconda Prompt**

The same results above is showed

But in workstation2 I can't execute pip at Anaconda Prompt (only at windows command prompt )
**Windows Command Prompt**

The same results above is showed

**Anaconda Prompt**

```
(C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3) C:\Users\myuser>pip show pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in run_module_as_main
"_ main __", mod_spec)
File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip.exe_main.py", line 9, in
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Can somebody help me fix this error?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try with `pip3` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble installing TextBlob with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58442401/trouble-installing-textblob-with-pip)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+TypeError%3A+%27module%27+object+is+not+callable

Comment: "Location: c:\program files (x86)\python 3.7.1\lib\site-packages" and the fact that you're using Anaconda leads to the assumption that you're having multiple Python installations on your machine. Depending on your `PATH` settings, calling things from `cmd` vs. Anaconda Prompt can give quite different results.