# Problems with pip3 and pipenv with Mac OS Catalina fresh install

Tags: python-3.x, pip, homebrew, zsh, macos-catalina

I installed xcode dev tools first using

```
%xcode-select --install
```

then I installed Homebrew using

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

then I did

```
%brew install python3

%pip3 install pipenv
```

but when I call

```
%pip3
```

I get

```
% pip3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/pip3", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

This is where it says my pip3 and python3 are located

```
% which pip3
/usr/bin/pip3

% which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

Can someone please help me solve this problem. I am trying to learn to program but I can't continue without fixing this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble installing TextBlob with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58442401/trouble-installing-textblob-with-pip)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+TypeError%3A+%27module%27+object+is+not+callable

Answer (score 12, accepted):

MacOS Catalina ships with it's own versions of `python3` and `pip3`, so this is probably conflicts between macOS and Brew-installed Python libraries. I solved similar issues by no longer using Brew for anything related to Python.

My recommendation: From a fresh install of Catalina, run `sudo pip3 install pipenv`. Create a separate directory for each project you work on, and run `pipenv shell` from that directory every time you work on it. Don't ever bother installing any packages system-wide, and don't overwrite macOS's Python. Anything you do, do inside a Pipenv managed virtual environment -- only install packages via `pipenv install <pkg>`.

Doing all this will keep the right version of the Python binary and all related packages inside a directory inside `~/.local/share/virtualenvs/` for each project. This way, future macOS updates shouldn't every break dependencies.

Comment: I ended up downloading high sierra instead of Catalina. But I will keep this in mind if I switch back to Catalina

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem after upgrading to Catalina since I was already using homebrew and Python/pipenv stopped to work as expected. My Python crashed every time, I ran `pipenv install` with an error described in this [developer.apple.com thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/119429). The answer by [Mickey Ristroph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/129126/mickey-ristroph) sounds like a okay'ish workaround, but it doesn't really solve the problem.

I want to be able to use homebrew for all my MacOS installed software - including Python. But there was help, since the problem was the usage of a wrong version `libcrypto dylib` version. To fix the issue, update & upgrade brew packages and be sure `openssl` is installed:

```
brew update && brew upgrade && brew install openssl
```

Then we create new symbolic links to the homebrew installed `libssl.dylib` and `libcrypto.dylib` libraries:

```
# go to homebrew installed openssl dir:
cd /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2t/lib
sudo cp libssl.1.0.0.dylib libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/

cd /usr/local/lib
# if there are links already, you may backup them:
mv libssl.dylib libssl_bak.dylib
mv libcrypto.dylib libcrypto_bak.dylib

# now create new symbolic links:
sudo ln -s libssl.1.0.0.dylib libssl.dylib
sudo ln -s libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib libcrypto.dylib
```

Now my homebrew installed Python (and `pipenv`) works like a charm again.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the raw command used to install libraries and supports in macOS Catalina to this:

```
python3 -m pip install pipenv
```

(instead of `pip3 install pipenv`)