# Why is pip3 not working after I upgraded it?

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I ran `pip3 upgrade pip` and after that, pip3 stopped working, every time I tried to use it, it gave me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble installing TextBlob with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58442401/trouble-installing-textblob-with-pip)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+TypeError%3A+%27module%27+object+is+not+callable

Answer (score -1):

before you can insatll pip

sudo apt- install python3-pip

Answer (score -1):

if you upgrade pip then command for windows :

python -m pip install --upgrade pip

for Linux

python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip